# D3, remove the .enter created div "bubble.selectAll("circle").remove();"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3JS, And learning by own,

What I am planing to do is, create the circle and erase after creation, and after 800 ms, create again like wise it goes.

I need to know, What I am doing wrong here.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>


     var bubble = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", '400px')
        .attr('height', '400px')
        .selectAll(".circle");
        //animat();
        function animat(){    

        bubble.data([1,2,3,4,5])
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d,i) {
          return d*10*(i+1);
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d,i) {
          return d*10*(i+1);
        })
        .attr("r", function(d,i) {
          return (i+1)*d*5;
        })
        .attr("fill", 'rgba(200,200,300,0.4)');
         d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", '400px')
        .attr('height', '400px');
    bubble.selectAll("circle").remove(); // I want to erase the whole svg content , so that next run will create once again, Is it Wrong ? 

        }

        setInterval(animat, 1800);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong here

```
bubble.selectAll("circle").remove();
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsbin.com/jigelipi/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in your bubble-variable, as you use

```
.selectAll(".circle")
```

in the beginning which refers to a class, and later

```
.selectAll("circle")
```

to select all circles. and by calling

```
bubble.selectAll("circles").remove()
```

you double it, as it reads internally

```
d3.select("body").selectAll(".circle").selectAll("circle").remove()
```

try the following:

```
var bubble = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", '400px')
    .attr('height', '400px');

bubble.selectAll("circle").data([1,2,3,4,5])
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d,i) {
      return d*10*(i+1);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d,i) {
      return d*10*(i+1);
    })
    .attr("r", function(d,i) {
      return (i+1)*d*5;
    })
    .attr("fill", 'rgba(200,200,300,0.4)');
}
```

and to remove use

```
bubble.selectAll("circle").remove();
```

however, as your code is at the moment, the circle gets removed instantly after drawing, so you won't see anything. you could put the remove-line at the top of your function:

```
function animat(){
bubble.selectAll("circle").remove();
```

that clears the circles and draws new ones, but you won't see any change as there is no delay.

i imagine you want to have some sort of visual effect deleting the circle, so you could do something like this (again, right at the top of your function):

```
bubble.selectAll("circle").transition().duration(1000).remove();
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/jigelipi/5/edit

edit: to make it a little smoother:
    bubble.selectAll("circle").transition().duration(500).attr("fill",'rgba(200,200,300,0)').remove();

demo: http://jsbin.com/jigelipi/10/edit